# Use different image resolutions for different iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, asset-catalog

I have an image that I would like to display in my iOS app. To conserve memory, I would like to display the lowest possible resolution that still matches the number of physical pixels on the device

For example, could be displayed as a square 1/4 the height of the device. So the sizes would be as follows

> **iPhone 4s**        240x240 px
>
> **iPhone 5/5s**     284x284 px
>
> **iPhone 6**          334x334 px
>
> **iPhone 6+**        480x480 px

I've looked into asset catalogs, but I don't see any way to have a different image for iPhone 4s, iPhone 5/5s, and iPhone 6 (they are `@2x`). The only difference is iPhone 6+ (`@3x`).

I've also tried adding the `Retina 4 2x` option, but that only gives a different icon for the iPhone 5/5s - there is still no way to differentiate between 4s and 6.

[image]

I understand that I could choose the image programmatically based on the device, but asset catalogs only downloads the necessary images to the users device (not sure if that is true, I remember reading something about it, though), making the application take up less storage. It would be inefficient to include four images, if only one will be used.

Is there any way to use a different image resolution for every iOS device with a different amount of physical pixels?

Note that I'm **not** asking about scaling the image, but about getting the correct resolution used (a different image for *every* device), so less RAM will be taken when it is displayed.

Comment: Downvoter, can you please explain why this question isn't good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just creating a different file for every device, and naming them `imageName@size`, so for an image of a dog that is `128x128`, the file would be named `dog@128`.

Here's the code that I used to do this

```
func getPNGImageForSize(size: Float, named: String) -> UIImage?{
    //the image size will be measured in points, which is the unit that is used
    //when setting the frames of UIViews. To turn this into pixels, it must be
    //multiplied by the screen's render scale (on an iPhone 6+, 1 point is equal
    //to 3 pixels, or 9 pixels in 2 dimensions (3^2).
    let scaled: Int = Int(ceil(size * Float(UIScreen.mainScreen().scale))
    let imageName: String = "\(named)@\(scaled)"

    //ofType set to png, because this image is a PNG
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(imageName, ofType: "png")

    return UIImage(contentsOfFile: (path ?? ""))
}
```

And to call it, I simply use

```
getPNGImageForSize(Float(self.view.frame.height / 4), named: "dog")
```

which would result in the following images, depending on the device

> **iPhone 4s**           dog@240.png
>
> **iPhone 5/5s**        dog@284.png
>
> **iPhone 6**             dog@334.png
>
> **iPhone 6+**           dog@480.png

This could also be altered to work with non-square images, named `imageName@width-height`

```
func getPNGImageForSize(width: Float, height: Float, named: String) -> UIImage?{  
    let scaledWidth: Int = Int(ceil(width * Float(UIScreen.mainScreen().scale))
    let scaledHeight: Int = Int(ceil(height * Float(UIScreen.mainScreen().scale))
    let imageName: String = "\(named)@\(width)-\(height)"

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(imageName, ofType: "png")

    return UIImage(contentsOfFile: (path ?? ""))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your image as to what it may look like in iPhone6+ which will consume the @3x images, then scale down to its @2x image size which will be consumed by iPhone4S to iPhone6 devices and then further scale your image to @1x which earlier versions of iPad devices use.

Create 3 different images with 3 scales of `@1x` `@2x` and `@3x`.

there are 3 only, Older iPhone - 3S, 4, non retina iPad all consume @1x images, whereas iPad Air, iPad retina , iPhone 4S - iPhone 6 uses @2x and iPhone 6+ uses @3x
FYI
I have answered this question before here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32355413/3755838)

[Here](https://www.codeandweb.com/blog/2012/12/14/scaling-content-for-retina-display-iphone-and-ipad) is another good blog about image scaling in IOS devices (all of them)

## EDIT

and about clearing your doubt about how come iPhone5 and 6 use @2x images.
Well iPhone5 uses the same image that is for iPhone6 i.e @2x images despite of the height as iPhone5 scales down @2x into its own limit hence there is nothing to worry about this. Xcode takes care of this quite efficiently.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is asking how to have a different image for **EVERY** iOS device

Comment: have edited the answer if it still confuses you then plz comment will be happy to clear the confusion

Comment: Still, there are only 3 options (one of which is only for older iphones, so actually 2) of places to store the images - to have a different image for every device, there needs to be 4, because although some devices have the same scale factor, each device has a different amount of pixels

Comment: There is no getting around with this, if you want to use image assets you got to let xcode choose the device and select the correct image for you.
OR you can choose separate storyboards to load each storyboard with each unique image sets for different devices..

I have edited the answer once again for your understanding

Comment: exactly - the point of the question is how to get around this