# How To Prepare Image Assets in iOS supporting both iPads and iPhones?

Tags: ios

I usually do not care much about my assets even if I support the iPads in my project. As long as the imageView for the background of the app is set to Aspect Fill.

Also, here are some links I've found, but not so related to this question.

1. OLD Question and old answers: [How to support both iPad and iPhone retina graphics in universal apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611061/how-to-support-both-ipad-and-iphone-retina-graphics-in-universal-apps)
2. Cool question and cool answers, however, question and answers focus merely in iPhones:
   [iOS: Preparing background images for applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250333/ios-preparing-background-images-for-applications)

Going back to the question, if I have an Adobe XD file or Sketch, or Photoshop or whatever file that lets me export an image/asset, in what resolution should I start? Do I start with the largest possible size (for iPad Pro) which is 1024x1366 then let the software cut the sizes into @1x and @2x?

If I'm only to support the iPhones, then this would be way lots easier. Thank you!

Comment: You want to make appropriate [assets catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/) for you purposes and it shows all required resolutions you need.

Comment: Ok, that was very helpful. Do I delete this question or wait for someone to give it a downvote? Maybe you could give an answer that might be a spoonfeed, though this comment is enough. Thanks.

Comment: Did not dare to make such a vague answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If your source is vector based, then (obviously?) it's a non-issue...

With bitmap / raster images, you *almost always* get better results by scaling down.

Depending on the image itself (a photo tends to scale much better than a line-drawing), you *may* not be happy with simple "auto-gen" features... in which case, you'd need to manually "scale and tweak".

(Hope that helps).