# Background image size guidelines to work on All iOS Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, size, background-image, dimensions

Currently I am facing one issue where we need to have all screens with one background image so I have created Master Controller and all child controllers are inherited from this Master controller.

The issue is we have placed 1x, 2x, 3x Background image size and 
When it loads on iPhone X then its fine but then on some other device it is streched or shrieked based on the dimensions.

Currently the image size for background image in Project is :-

1x :- 320 × 568
2x :- 750 × 1334
3x :- 1125 × 2436 (iPhone X)

Also tried 3x size as 1242*2436 & 1242*2208 (7 Plus)

I have followed many links to get the issue resolved.

For e.g :-
[iOS: Preparing background images for applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250333/ios-preparing-background-images-for-applications)

Also if we try to change content mode of ImageView then image placing is not same for all devices. Which is another requirement that image should look same and should be on same position on all devices.

I know this is very basic question but I have researched regarding it a lot and not able to find the solution.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you check splash screen image mechanism how splash adjust in all screen without stretch? Same logic will apply in your case.

Comment: And how I will be able to check splash screen image mechanism?
I mean that is handled by iOS right?