# Do I need the different image sizes for the Xcode assets?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been a little bit concerned over whether I should fill up all my assets with the respective universal sizes:

[image]

I have around 20-30 images so it'd be a concern if I have to add three png's per asset. Is this required to submit my application? My app has run fine without the other sizes? (x2, x3)

Comment: This is not required for submitting your application to the AppStore

Comment: If you did not add 2x, 3x. 1x will be used on all other higher resolution device and looks pixelated. There might be a chance apple can reject because of UI.

Comment: All my images are 1000px big. I have tested my app on an iPad pro and it looks just as good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need image assets for all dimentions!
Think like this - you didn't provide image assets for all of them and the system start to upscaling or downscaling the image as result the system will do more work from expected. And now imagine that you put 2 or 3 in TableView or CollectionView for example. All of the scalled images must be stored somewhere ... ofcourse everything is comming with the price.

**In short it is to decrease memory/disk usage so it is all about increasing performance and user experience.**

Check this discussion [Why do I need @1x, @2x and @3x iOS images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354453/why-do-i-need-1x-2x-and-3x-ios-images)