# Is it possible to not include 1x of image asserts in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

When I include 2x images only, it will show `The asset assets/icons/xxx.png does not exist.`.

Must I include the 1x image version? Since iOS iPhones all provide retina screen(2x or 3x).

PS: I was making a app support iPhone only, and iOS 12+

Answer (score 0):

[from the flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#resolution-aware)

> The main asset is assumed to correspond to a resolution of 1.0. For
>   example, consider the following asset layout for an image named
>   my_icon.png:
>
> ```
> content_copy
>   .../my_icon.png
>   .../2.0x/my_icon.png
>   .../3.0x/my_icon.png
> ```
>
> On devices with a device pixel ratio of 1.8, the asset
>   `.../2.0x/my_icon.png` would be chosen. For a device pixel ratio of
>   2.7, the asset `.../3.0x/my_icon.png` would be chosen.
>
> Each entry in the asset section of the pubspec.yaml should correspond
>   to a real file, **with the exception of the main asset entry.** If the
>   main asset entry does not correspond to a real file, then the asset
>   with the lowest resolution is used as the fallback for devices with
>   device pixel ratios below that resolution. The **entry should still be
>   included** in the pubspec.yaml manifest, however.

You may include the 1x Image to accommodate for older iPads and iPhones.

[check this link for further info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354453/why-do-i-need-1x-2x-and-3x-ios-images)

Comment: Actually,  I was make app from target iOS 12.0,  so 1x image is not need for iPhone only(Not include iPad) with iOS 12.0+

Comment: That's why I ask, why include useless image ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Share your `pubspec.yaml` file's code if you still get the error.

Comment: My question is it possible or way to **not** include the 1x images since I not used them.  Not the usually situation when include assets.

Comment: There is no mandatory requirement for you to include the 1x image but I think there's an error in your pubspec.yaml file and that's the reason for this error.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you'll need to add them to `pubspec.yaml` directly.

So, if you have `<path>/2.0x/image.webp` and `<path>/3.0x/image.webp`, then you add

```
- <path>/image.webp
```

to `pubspec.yaml`
and it'll work even if there's no image.webp in path.