# How to convert image for iOS 1x, 2x, 3x?

Tags: ios, image

I have a PNG image that is 1200x1200. How do I resize/convert this for my iOS app for 1x, 2x, and 3x images?

Thanks

Comment: Preview.app, /usr/bin/sips?

Comment: Is the 1200x1200 pixels needed for 1x, 2x or 3x? Once you answer that, simply scale the image for the other 2. Of course if you need to make the image bigger, simply scaling will give a bad image.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26572313/1630618

Comment: You can used online converter, try this -> https://appicon.co/#image-sets

Comment: There are many online tool out there https://www.iconcutter.com

Answer (score 3):

I usually use sketch for resizing image easily.

1. You need to set width and height to 400
2. Click on the plus icon on the bottom right corner, It says make exportable.
3. It'll automatically create the 1x. You can add other size by clicking plus again.