# Why is my image in UIImageView always blurry?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, resolution, pixel

I am trying to insert an image into the UIImageView which I have set to 120 x 120 pixels but every time I drop an image in it is blurry. What do I need to do to get the right resolution image on the image view?

Comment: Your image is 120 x 120 points.  You need to add 240 x 240 pixel and 360 x 360 pixel images to your asset catalog.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26572313/1630618

Answer (score 0):

Create 2x and 3x assets for your image.